# Debug one unit test in VSCode

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-code

I have a number of unit tests in VSCode which I want to debug.  The problem is I want to debug only one unit test.  By default VS Code runs all the unit tests.  I want to specify only one unit test to run like in Visual Studio.  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: what language? there's a "Run unit test method" command for python

Answer (score 1):

According to the unit test framework you are using you should be able to create a `config.json` or something similar where you can set options for your tests. Within this config you should be able to specify the path of all unit tests that shall be executed. For example when you are running javaScript unit tests with [jasmine](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine) you can set something like this in your `config.json`:

```json
"spec_dir": "./out/test/unittest",
"spec_files": [
    "**/*[tT]est.js"
]
```

[Here](https://mochajs.org/#the-test-directory) you can check out how this behavior is done with mocha. To run only one unit test you just set an absolute path. For example

```json
"spec_files": [
        "./path/to/a/single/unittest.js"
    ]
```